# Birt report not working after deploying on Tomacat server

Tags: java, birt, actuate

I am using BIRT reports 4.2 in my web application and I have integrated all the reports on JSP pages. I have deployed my application on my test server which is having Apache Tomcat 8.0. After login to my application the reports are not opening like following image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujJh8.png). If test the application on my local machine while running with eclipse the reports opening. If its the test server application I am accessing with https://testServerIP/appName (Reports are not working) where as if I run my application in my local machine I am accessing reports. The only difference with test server and local machine to access the  application is accessing with my IP and Port with http in local machine and in test server as above mentioned link  . Please help me out from this issue.
Thank you..

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, consider making a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO's help and take a look of how to do a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I got the solution by adding baseurl of my server with port in Webcontent/WEB-INF/viewer.properties like following base_url= HTTP://serverIP:8443.

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Please write a answer and accept it to describe your problem for future reference

Comment: And also we have to enable Display Mixed Content in IE-> Internet Options ->Miscellaneous -> Display Mixed Content

Comment: But the solution not solved my problem totally because, BAR charts are not opening but if I click on save the report the chart is coming to PDF document. Table reports I am able to access.